# Devise: When resending confirmation email, change flash message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm setting up Devise such that users can log in and use the site without having confirmed their email address, similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957827/devise-soft-email-confirmation). But there are a couple of features on the site that users can't use unless they've confirmed.

OK, that's fine. I can check for `current_user.confirmed?`. If they're not confirmed, I can put a button on the page to have them request the confirmation be sent again.

The issue I'm having is that when they do this while logged in, the flash message they see on the result page is "You are already signed in." Which isn't ideal - I just want to put up the message that the confirmation was sent.

I'm starting down the path of trying to figure out which method of the `Devise::ConfirmationController` to override, and to what, but I'm hoping someone has done this already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason the flash says "You are already signed in" is because the user is being redirected to `new_session_path` from the `after_resending_confirmation_instructions_path_for` method. I would override this method to check if they are logged in. If they are, then don't redirect to `new_session_path`, set your flash message and redirect to another page.

Override the confirmations controller by putting it in `controllers/users/confirmations_controller.rb`

```
class Users::ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController

  protected

  def after_resending_confirmation_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
    if signed_in?
      flash[:notice] = "New message here" #this is optional since devise already sets the flash message
      root_path
    else
      new_session_path(resource_name)
    end
  end
end
```

Add your confirmationsController to routes->

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:confirmations => 'users/confirmations' }
```

Comment: Winner winner! Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help out! I just happened to be working on the same use case.

Comment: I changed this slightly, using the following code to set the flash message from the translations file instead: `set_flash_message(:notice, :send_instructions)`

Comment: Actually, you don't even have to set the flash message since devise already sets the :send_instructions message when the confirmation is submitted.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should look something like this:

```
module Devise
  module ConfirmationsController
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      alias_method_chain :show, :new_flash
    end

    def show_with_new_flash
      # do some stuff
      flash[:notice] = "New message goes here"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Per https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/confirmations_controller.rb, `ConfirmationsController` isn't a module, it's a class. Have you done this yourself?

Comment: I done it but in 1 year old project and don't know if it will work with latests ruby/gem versions.

Answer (score 0):

Could edit

config/locales/devise.en.yml to be more relavent at line:

```
failure:
  already_authenticated: 'You are already signed in.'
```

or you could do this in your view where flash message has been added

```
<%=content_tag :div, msg, id: "flash_#{name}" unless msg.blank? or msg == "You are already signed in."%>
```

Comment: This isn't exactly right, because then the error is also changed for the case when the user really does try to sign in twice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Devise 3.1.0, there's a different method for this scenario instead of after_resending_confirmation_instructions_path_for described in the top voted answer. I modified mine like so:

```
class Users::ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController

  protected

  def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
    if signed_in?
      set_flash_message(:notice, :confirmed)
      root_path
    elsif Devise.allow_insecure_sign_in_after_confirmation
      after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    else
      new_session_path(resource_name)
    end
  end
end
```